# Some very basic geometry problem basis

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am studying  Riemannian geometry and have some very basic background for differential geometry.In differential geometry, I only know about thing in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ , when it comes to some abstract space , my books use  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} $ and $dx_i$ to denote the basis of tangent space and the cotangent space.

I don't know what is the meaning of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} $, because I think it is a differential operator rather than a basis element , what is the meaning of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} $ at some point $p$? May I have some reference book or material for this basic thing? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a differential operator, but in the setting of abstract smooth manifolds, tangent vectors are often *defined* as differential operators. This is a standard technique you can find in any graduate-level differential geometry book, such as John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

You can also find many questions on this site that explain why we define tangent vectors this way. See, for example, ["Why do we think of a vector as being the same as a differential operator?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502900/why-do-we-think-of-a-vector-as-being-the-same-as-a-differential-operator)

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP asked for a book, and I gave one of the standard references.

Comment: But in $\mathbb{R}^3$，$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} =e_i$， how can i get it?

Comment: @mnmn1993: I have no idea what "how can I get it?" means.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$，why $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} =e_i$?

Comment: @mnmn1993: go read a differential geometry book, or the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

At the spaces $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$ things like 
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ 
are interpreted as a mechanism to answer how a scalar function 
$f:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ changes or varies, through the calculation of
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ 
and evaluating at a point
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p)$, to get that information. 
Here $\Omega$ is a subset in $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$.